# VBScript ExitCode from batch files to Jenkins

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am executing a batch command Window Build step on Jenkins wich runs a VbScript which in turn runs a few batchfiles. 
Now I need to be able to see some feedback on jenkins console output view from the vbscript- for some reason regardless of the success of the batch files that run from the script i always get Exit 0 SUCCESS,

anyways of reliable system i could use within the VBScript to get sometracing on Jenkins??

Comment: This is certainly doable. However, we need to see your VBScript code to be able to tell you why it's not working the way you expect.

Comment: I figured if I run the .vbs file through jenkins with cscript then i will see the echo messages back , which is great, basicaly answered my own question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here i basicaly answered my own question

If I run the VBS file from Jenkins with a pre agrument of cscript then I can see some output on there using `wscript.echo "MyMessage"`

I also had to then set the Host Default Script to CScript like below

```
cscript //h:cscript //s
```